# Both my opponent and I are in Waiting mode for the game?

Tags: draw-something

The game is Waiting at Both me and my opponent. We have tried to nudge eachother bur it Does not come up - What do we do?

Comment: This seems more like a OMGPOP (the makers of draw something) question, have you tried re-installing the app on both devices.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen.  Both of you reboot your devices and when you restart, only one of you should have the option to play.